# Render list in ordered structure without unicode characters

Tags: python, templates, unicode, ansible, jinja2

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[(u'Element1', u'Description1', u'Status1), (u'newElement2', u'newDescription2', u'newStatus2), (u'nextElement3', u'nextDescription3', u'nextStatus3), (u'anotherElement4', u'anotherDescription4', u'anotherStatus4)]
```

I have an ansible playbook that uses a jinja2 template to render the list to a text file. The template file looks like this:

```
{% for item in description | batch(3, '&nbsp;') %}
{% for el in item %}
{{ el }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this returns the text file to look like this:

```
[u'Element1', u'Description1', u'Status1]
[u'newElement2', u'newDescription2', u'newStatus2]
[u'nextElement3', u'nextDescription3', u'nextStatus3]
[u'anotherElement4', u'anotherDescription4', u'anotherStatus4]
```

What I want the report to look like is this:

```
Element1           Description1           Status1
newElement2        nextDescription2       newStatus2
nextElement3       nextDescription3       nextStatus3
anotherElement4    anotherDescription4    anotherDescription4
```

Is there a way to remove the unicode characters and render the lists this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
{% for row in description %}
{% for cell in row %}
{{ "%-22s"|format(cell) }} 
{%- endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Yields:

```
Element1              Description1          Status1
newElement2           newDescription2       newStatus2
nextElement3          nextDescription3      nextStatus3
anotherElement4       anotherDescription4   anotherStatus4
```

---

But to get a dynamic padding - depending on a max length of an element in a column - looks like a much more complex task: `{{ "%-22s"|format(cell) }}` can be replaced with `{{ "{0}".format(cell).ljust(width) }}` where `width` can be a variable, but likely it would require another loop first to collect the lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
{% for el in item %}
    {% for e in el %}
        {{ e }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or use html tables if you want to be able to change formatting

Comment: This renders everything on top of each other, any idea on the best way to have it in a formatting order?

Comment: use html tables